# Connect to db using variables dont work with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, connection

Im trying to get modern and use mysqli like this

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

but it dosent work,

This works

```
$connect = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

am i just tired or is it completly wrong?

Comment: you need to use `mysqli_select_db` when you are using mysqli_

Comment: use mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in your select database line, you did mix it with `mysql_*` when you should use `mysqli_*`

Your should use `mysqli_select_db` for selecting database using `mysqli_*` extension.

Your final code would be something like this:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($connect, $dbname);
```

Comment: *"

You should do:

$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($dbname);

"* -  they should do this because of? plus this will fail. who upvoted this? read up on the function http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php `bool mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Sir @Fred-ii-. I will keep in mind your recommendations for future..

Comment: You're welcome ;-) now the OP will be well on their way; *cheers*

Comment: you very welcome. Glad I could help you well. @user3437732